# Second line of powershell script not working

Tags: powershell

I’m deploying this PowerShell script via SCCM 2012 in our environment.
The script is saved on a shared location: \exeample\test\test1
When I run the script locally it works. So I saved it in ps1 format then created a test collection in SCCM. I deployed it into my test collection and make it available for users. I see the script in software center and its installing ok but the second line of the script is not working. 
The create script option is not enable.

I the code above but second line is not uninstalling

```
#Delete STM
#Delete STM manuals folder and shortcuts

$LinkPath = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\STM"


$folder = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\STM - manual"


Remove-Item $LinkPath -Force -Recurse; Remove-Item $folder -Force -Recurse
```

There is no error message. The script is available in software and can be installed but it's not removing start menu icon. Sorry I'm new to powershell and to the forum I hope that I posted correctly

Comment: What happens if you execute the code by hand? Does it work?

Comment: I'd guess that a _start menu icon_ is a shortcut (a `.lnk` file).

Comment: Repeat Daily, yes it works by hand

Comment: JosefZ, yes it's a .Lnk

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the extension of the file or wildcard character pattern in `$folder` variable if you want to remove **specific shortcuts**. Otherwise it is correct for removing folder.

Do you have **permission to delete** the folder or You have to **run as Admin** rights to remove Item from `Start Menu` hence it affects to all users

Comment: By wildcard, you mean get-childitem? I do have permission to delete the folder and the shortcuts but since it will be deployed through powershell the script will use the normal user credential (unless I'm mistaken). Thank you for your help...